# Mysqli query no result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm having an issue in mysqli prepare query that i cannot figure out what is wrong.

In phpmyadmin i'm writing this query

```
SELECT `country_id` FROM `oa_country` WHERE `name` = "Ελλάδα"
```

And i get a successful result.

[image]

When I try to do that with a mysqli prepare statement i get an error.

```
function getCountryId($country) {
    print($country); \\prints "Ελλάδα" or anything else, even countries in latin letters.
    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
    $result = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT `country_id` FROM `oa_country` WHERE `name` = ? ;");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, 's', $country);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result, $countcountry);
    print_r($result);\\ see below.
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result))
      {
            $countryid = $countcountry;

      }
    mysqli_stmt_close($result);
    mysqli_close($db);

    echo $countryid; \\undefined variable countryid
    return $countryid;
}
```

Print $result prints those data.

```
mysqli_stmt Object
(
    [affected_rows] => -1
    [insert_id] => 0
    [num_rows] => 0
    [param_count] => 1
    [field_count] => 1
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [id] => 1
)
```

The weird thing is that it used to work, but all of a sudden stopped and i can't explain why !

P.S. All inserts are working with mysqli + prepare statements.
Queries like these stopped working.

**Update 1.**

---

I've done this error logging above my class

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

And now i get this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Column 'country_id' cannot be null' in /some/url/lib/registerClass.php:49
Stack trace:
#0 /some/url/lib/registerClass.php(49): mysqli_stmt_execute(Object(mysqli_stmt))
#1 /some/url/register.php(34): RegisterLibrary->Address(21267, 'kapa\n', '\xCE\x9D\xCE\xAC\xCF\x84\xCF\x83\xCE\xB9\xCE\xBF\xCF\x82', 'oriste', 'pws', '123123', 'asdasd', '4121sadsa', 'sadas', '13322', '\xCE\x95\xCE\xBB\xCE\xBB\xCE\xAC\xCE\xB4\xCE\xB1', '\xCE\x91\xCF\x84\xCF\x84\xCE\xB9\xCE\xBA\xCE\xAE')
```

And below the `$db` variable i set the charset to utf8.

```
function getCountryId($country) {
    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
    mysqli_set_charset( $db, 'utf8' );
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT country_id FROM oa_country WHERE name=?")) {

        /* bind parameters for markers */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $country);

        /* execute query */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        /* bind result variables */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $countryidr);
        $thecountryid = $countryidr;
        echo $thecountryid;  //no echo.
        /* fetch value */
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    } 
    return $thecountryid;  //no return.
}
```

Comment: maybe try to set mysqli_set_charset

Comment: @bxN5 i guess it has to do with charset then. see the updated question!

Comment: @bxN5 ok i setted up the charset correctly and it worked. if you want to answer it i will accept it :)

Comment: it'd be cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like charset problem

try to set mysqli_set_charset